# How to troubleshoot/debug Oracle permission problems

Tags: oracle, security, oracle-11g, logs, permissions

An application is connecting to Oracle to do stuff. It's not working but I don't get any ORA errors in the application itself. I'm thinking its a permission problem. So my question is what is the best way to check to see if a oracle account  tried to perform an operation that it didn't have permission to do? It would also help to know what operation it tried to perform so I can grant it.

Comment: You say "it's not working" but you don't say what *actually* happens. Obviously the database operations don't work but what happens when you *try*? Does your application throw an exception or return an error code? If so, is it anything remotely useful?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Nothing helpful from the application level so I need to venture to the database level. The application is performing database operations as a specific Oracle user so if I can trace the operations the Oracle account is making I can see if the issue is a permission problem or not.

Comment: If missing permissions were the cause, the database raises an error. It never silently fails (at least not Oracle). If you don't see any errors this either means the statements are not executed at all or the application swallows the error message.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right, I don't know if the application is not giving me the ORA error or not. Lets assume there is actually an ORA error and the application isn't surfacing it. Do I need to turn on auditing for all actions of this user or something?

Comment: If the application doesn't show you the errors, then you'll need to turn on full auditing in Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option (short of full auditing) is a servererror trigger for the schema in question (or the whole database).

```
drop table error_log;
create table error_log (error_time timestamp, username varchar(50), msg varchar(4000), stmt varchar(4000));

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER servererror_trigger 
  AFTER SERVERERROR
  ON SCHEMA
declare
   sql_text ora_name_list_t;
   msg_     varchar2(2000) := null;
   stmt_    varchar2(2000) := null;
begin

  for depth in 1 .. ora_server_error_depth loop
    msg_ := msg_ || ora_server_error_msg(depth);
  end loop;

  for i in 1 .. ora_sql_txt(sql_text) loop
     stmt_ := stmt_ || sql_text(i);
  end loop;

  insert into error_log
  (error_time, username, msg, stmt)
  values 
  (current_timestamp, ora_login_user, msg_, stmt_);
end;
/
```

If it's for a single schema/user the trigger needs to be created under that user. You also can trap errors for the whole *database* by specifying `ON DATABASE`. In that case you'll need to create that trigger and the table as DBA I assume (haven't tried that).

Now nearly all errors that happen will be recorded by the trigger (see the manual for a list of errors that will not be reported: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS1992)

Comment: I'm not having much luck with the trigger. I created 2 users to replicate the scenario. I tried to create a table as user1 in user2's tablespace and got the expected `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` error but nothing was captured in the `error_log` table. I created the trigger as user1 and user2 and the two error_log tables created were empty after receiving the permission error. I also tried `ON DATABASE` but I had to run that one as the sys account because the test accounts didn't have enough permissions to do that.